# set size of window to minimum size before scroll bar appears C#

Tags: c#, winforms, size

Basicaly i am trying to set the window size automatically to the minimum size before the scroll bar appears, logically I am thinking that if I set the size of the window to this size and all the components should be shown no problem, I tried a couple of the answers answering the other questions but that didn't work, minimum size is 0.

When I start up my application it doesn't show the full content, i am using a telerik report viewer(if anyone knows what it is) in a radform, but don't mind the names, the report viewer and radform are just extensions of the known winform and component so the same rules apply.

The thing is when I show the window it won't show the full component, it's mostly the horizontal scrollbar I need to remove by resizing the window.

I tried outputing the autoscrollminize property on both the form and the component but they are both 0,0 however if the scrollbar appears and disappears when I resize the window manually there should be a property/value somewhere I could use to set the windowsize from the start.

**technical info:**
the component is already docked
if I undock the reportviewer component the scrollbar appears inside this component so the key is to figure out when the vertical scrollbar will appear depending on the data in this component

I already tried
setting the autosize property to true for the window and setting the size to 10,10
finding minimum size/AutoScrollMinSize
Setting the size to preferred size(when I do this the window takes on the absolute smallest possible size showing only the title bar.)

Comment: you don't need to tell us how to answer questions here, most of the users who is willing to help you knows very well how to do it, so no need to be rude...

Comment: it's not being rude... I'm saving you time

Comment: I simply cannot walk away from this page without saying this.

Comment: and would you please stop downvoting my question?
@MrKWatkins LOL

Comment: I think this is a legitimate question that can be answered at least with some "how will I solve the situation" kind of answer

Answer (score 2):

the form minimus size is the minimum size that YOU set on the form, it's not a minimum value calculated for you.

You need to calculate/find-out the space needed by your controls, and then you'll have a value to set in the form height/width.
For calculating the space needed by your controls, it's up to you: maybe rows numbers multiplied by row height + header/footer height? or something like that.

You can even do some different research: if there are scrollbar, somewhere there is already the value you need, you only need to find it out.
For doing this kind of research there is a tiny free tool that is very useful

Hawkeye - The .Net Runtime Object Editor - http://hawkeye.codeplex.com/

It works like a property grid, but you can hook it to running .net programs, and it show you everything (properties value, private field value, object reference...) so you can try to dig in the scrollbars object to see if you can find out your height/width value.

Comment: thank you, I'd like to upvote you but I'm further from 15 now... gonna try this out

Comment: I think hawkeye is outdated, I can't get it to show anything, but downloaded the source and am trying to compile

Comment: @AndersM. I usually use it on .net 4 compiled project, and it works. My version is "1.2.5". I know there are different build for different .net framework version (.Net 2 / .Net 4)

Comment: client or just plain .net 4, I have it on 4 as well

Comment: @AndersM. If this can be of any use to you, here is the Hawkeye version I'm actually using  http://goo.gl/ecZxe  (the link will show you the zip file contents, then you should click the menu "File", and then "Download" (in the website, not in the browser :)))